# WP 7 - How to dim display in my app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, screen

I want dim (or bright) the display in my WP7 app. Do you have tips how do it this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this post [can we have a control on brightness of the screen in wp7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413850/can-we-have-a-control-on-brightness-of-the-screen-in-wp7)

It seems that there's no way of directly controlling the brightness, but you could make a transparent control on top of your app as described in the post.